# Rails - Adding a column to a table in specific order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

When running an ActiveRecord migration to add a new column to the table, it always gets added at the end of the table.

**I know this has no impact on performance or usability**, but from a human-readability point of view it gets annoying to not have similar columns grouped together for ease. For example I have a `password` field on my table and several months later decided to add a password modifier/salt so I add a `salt` column which gets added all the way on the end of the table.

Is there a way to control this? I suppose it might be db-dependent, so I'm using Postgres if that matters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL (or at least 9.5 and older) doesn't support adding columns anywhere except the end of the table, or changing the column order.

Live with the column being at the end.